# Problem with Simple Server Client program

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, server, serversocket

I have a problem with this simple server client program in Java. My goal is to implement a server which gets from the client a String array. The server has to sort these words alphabetically and send it back to the client. Finally the ordered words are printed in the console.

The problem is that I start the server and after starting  the client nothing appears on the console. Where is the mistake?

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Socket s = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    System.out.println("Server startet.......");
    try {

        server = new ServerSocket(6666);
        s = server.accept();
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String text = in.readLine();
        String array[] = text.split(";");
        Arrays.sort(array);

        String answer = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            answer = "" + array[i] + ";";
        }

        out.write(answer);
        out.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {

        try {

            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        try {

            server.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        try {

            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

}

}








public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String array[] = { "Hallo", "Bir", "Deme", "ABC" };
    question(array);

}

public static void question(String array[]) {

    Socket s = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {

        s = new Socket("localhost", 6666);
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            text += array[i] + ";";
        }

        out.write(text);
        out.flush();

        String answer = in.readLine();

        System.out.println(answer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        try {

            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `out.write(answer);  out.write("\n");` for the readLine.

Comment: Also consider at least printing the error message, when you get an exception.

Comment: I dont get an Exception. Only nothing appears

Comment: If I do this   out.write(answer); out.write("\n");  then only the first word of the Array, in this case "Hallo;" is printed on the console

Comment: Look at the construction of `answer` , it doesn't append the different parts, it is each time replaced by the last one (i.e a `+` is missing)

Comment: you could add some `System.out.println()` to print the messages before sending (after receiving) - or better some logging - so you could see what happened (helps a lot in production code)

Comment: I get it now. I have to write in the for loop the out.write() statement in the server class. Like this: for(){ out.write(array[i]+";")}  Why the hell it doesnt work with a String i dont know but now it works